# sbt - Server access error: Connection reset?

Tags: scala, sbt

I got the following error when run `sbt`.

```
PS H:\> sbt
Getting org.fusesource.jansi jansi 1.11  (this may take some time)...

:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
                module not found: org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.11

        ==== local: tried

          C:\Users\user1\.ivy2\local\org.fusesource.jansi\jansi\1.11\ivys\ivy.xml

          -- artifact org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.11!jansi.jar:

          C:\Users\user1\.ivy2\local\org.fusesource.jansi\jansi\1.11\jars\jansi.jar

        ==== local-preloaded-ivy: tried

          file:/C:/Users/user1/.sbt/preloaded/org.fusesource.jansi/jansi/1.11/ivys/ivy.xml

        ==== local-preloaded: tried

          file:/C:/Users/user1/.sbt/preloaded/org/fusesource/jansi/jansi/1.11/jansi-1.11.pom

          -- artifact org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.11!jansi.jar:

          file:/C:/Users/user1/.sbt/preloaded/org/fusesource/jansi/jansi/1.11/jansi-1.11.jar

        ==== Maven Central: tried

          https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/fusesource/jansi/jansi/1.11/jansi-1.11.pom

          -- artifact org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.11!jansi.jar:

          https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/fusesource/jansi/jansi/1.11/jansi-1.11.jar

        ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried

          https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.fusesource.jansi/jansi/1.11/ivys/ivy.xml

        ==== sbt-ivy-snapshots: tried

          https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/ivy-snapshots/org.fusesource.jansi/jansi/1.11/ivys/ivy.xml

                ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

                ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

                ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

                :: org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.11: not found

                ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::


:::: ERRORS
        Server access Error: Connection reset url=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/fusesource/jansi/jansi/1.11/jansi-1.11.pom

        Server access Error: Connection reset url=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/fusesource/jansi/jansi/1.11/jansi-1.11.jar

        Server access Error: Connection reset url=https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.fusesource.jansi/jansi/1.11/ivys/ivy.xml

        Server access Error: Connection reset url=https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/ivy-snapshots/org.fusesource.jansi/jansi/1.11/ivys/ivy.xml


:: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS
unresolved dependency: org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.11: not found
Error during sbt execution: Error retrieving required libraries
  (see C:\Users\user1\.sbt\boot\update.log for complete log)
Error: Could not retrieve jansi 1.11
```

However, I can get the file using `wget`?

```
PS H:\> wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/fusesource/jansi/jansi/1.11/jansi-1.11.pom


StatusCode        : 200
StatusDescription : OK
Content           : <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
                    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 h...
......
```

**Update:**
The following error message is from `update.log`.

> ERROR: Server access Error: Connection reset
>   url=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/fusesource/jansi/jansi/1.11/jansi-1.11.pom
>     Maven Central: resource not reachable for
>   org/fusesource/jansi#jansi;1.11:
>   res=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/fusesource/jansi/jansi/1.11/jansi-1.11.pom
>      trying
>   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/fusesource/jansi/jansi/1.11/jansi-1.11.jar
>         tried
>   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/fusesource/jansi/jansi/1.11/jansi-1.11.jar
>   ERROR: Server access Error: Connection reset
>   url=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/fusesource/jansi/jansi/1.11/jansi-1.11.jar
>     Maven Central: resource not reachable for
>   org/fusesource/jansi#jansi;1.11:
>   res=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/fusesource/jansi/jansi/1.11/jansi-1.11.jar
>     Maven Central: no ivy file nor artifact found for
>   org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.11 typesafe-ivy-releases: no namespace
>   defined: using system     no ivy file in cache for
>   org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.11: tried
>   C:\Users\user1.ivy2\cache\org.fusesource.jansi\jansi\ivy-1.11.xml
>   trying
>   https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.fusesource.jansi/jansi/1.11/ivys/ivy.xml
>         tried
>   https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.fusesource.jansi/jansi/1.11/ivys/ivy.xml
>   ERROR: Server access Error: Connection reset
>   url=https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.fusesource.jansi/jansi/1.11/ivys/ivy.xml
>     typesafe-ivy-releases: resource not reachable for
>   org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.11:
>   res=https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.fusesource.jansi/jansi/1.11/ivys/ivy.xml
>     typesafe-ivy-releases: no ivy file found for
>   org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.11 sbt-ivy-snapshots: no namespace
>   defined: using system     no ivy file in cache for
>   org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.11: tried
>   C:\Users\user1.ivy2\cache\org.fusesource.jansi\jansi\ivy-1.11.xml
>   trying
>   https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/ivy-snapshots/org.fusesource.jansi/jansi/1.11/ivys/ivy.xml
>         tried
>   https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/ivy-snapshots/org.fusesource.jansi/jansi/1.11/ivys/ivy.xml
>   ERROR: Server access Error: Connection reset
>   url=https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/ivy-snapshots/org.fusesource.jansi/jansi/1.11/ivys/ivy.xml
>     sbt-ivy-snapshots: resource not reachable for
>   org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.11:
>   res=https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/ivy-snapshots/org.fusesource.jansi/jansi/1.11/ivys/ivy.xml
>     sbt-ivy-snapshots: no ivy file found for
>   org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue - need to set proxy settings for https too.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue.Can you please help me where did you set and how you did ?

Answer (score 1):

looks like this is not a Powershell issue at all, regardless if you're receiving the error when using Powershell. Per the top of the error, looks like you're missing dependencies:

`module not found: org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.11`

the fact that `wget` works but `sbt` doesn't is because they are entirely different applications / exe's; `wget` is an alias for the Powershell cmdlet `Invoke-WebRequest` (run `Get-Command wget` to see this for yourself), while sbt is it's own application that I've honestly never heard or personally.

Comment: Yes I don't think power shell caused the issue. It's should be sbt issue